# Can we use decimal numbers (base-10) directly in MC6800?

Tags: assembly

In Motorolla 6800, can we use decimal numbers (base-10) directly like we use #$02 for hexadecimal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - omit the dollar sign.

Comment: Well, I am using this Hippy Motorolla 6800 Studio thing. And when I load my assembly code into the memory it adds dollar sign automatically. Could you offer me a better emulator, simulator or whatever for Windows running on Intel?

Comment: I can't - sorry - I haven't used 6800 in years.